# Can't find the pdflush thread?

Tags: linux-kernel

I just found out there's no pdflush on my Linux, v2.6.38. But when I do a

```
ps uax | grep flush
```

It shows:

```
root       269  0.1  0.0      0     0 ?        S    13:05   0:04 [flush-8:0]
```

My kernel is:

```
Linux yonggang-laptop 2.6.38-11-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 12 21:18:14 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

It seems [flush8:0] is a replacement of pdflush. Does anyone have further information about how this [flush-8:0] thread works and what does 8:0 mean? I know in old versions, the number of pdflush threads is 2-8 and it varies upon the system write back workload. I expect the [flush-8:0] thread to do something similar. In addition, why does /proc/sys/vm/nr_pdflush_threads still exist if there's no pdflush thread at all?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `flush` process is responsible for flushing data from temporary disk to permanent.  Its a replacement for the old `pdflush`, like you mentioned,  that claims much faster response time.  [The numbers you see refer to the block device it is monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621948/what-is-the-significance-of-the-numbers-in-the-name-of-the-flush-processes-for-n).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 8:0 corresponds to /sys/class/block/sda/dev on my computer, so this flush process should be working for the device /dev/sda. I get one more question: since the write back process is changed, does dirty_ratio and dirty_background_ratio still work in the same way as before?

Comment: I would say with 99% certainty that yes, they are still used and respected.  Because these settings exist in the `/proc/sys` framework, they would likely be removed if they were not used.